# bootstrap dropdown use flexbox and space-between for content to fill space

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I'd like to have two side menus in a dropdown in the navbar. In order to accomplish that I'd like to use flexbox. However the words are wrapping and i would like them not to and instead grow to fit the width of the content.

**Tip**: You'll need to expand the fiddle's rendering width to avoid the bootstrap collapse.
[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qprus35e/5/)

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <div class="flex-container">
              <div>
                <li><a href="#">Left Side</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Longer content on the left side</a></li>
              </div>
              <div>
                <li><a href="#">Log In</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
              </div>
            </div>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15055040/dynamic-width-for-twitter-bootstrap-dropdown-menu). I was looking to avoid setting a fixed min-width

```
.dropdown-menu > li > a {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the bootstrap's default style on `.dropdown-menu` with something like,

```
.dropdown-menu {
  min-width: 300px;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

FYI.. you can accomplish this by applying the "text-nowrap" class available in Bootstrap 5 to the ul or div elements.

```
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <div class="flex-container text-nowrap">
      <div>
```